# Why .net C# float is truncated to thousand in string representation?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, formatting, truncate

How come the following is possible ?

```
immediate console:
"{0:F20},{1:F20}, {2:F20}".format(
     res_ts, // float
     AppMgr.logon_info.res_ts, //float
     res_ts - AppMgr.logon_info.res_ts
)
"{0},{1}, {2}".format(
     res_ts, 
     AppMgr.logon_info.res_ts, 
     res_ts - AppMgr.logon_info.res_ts
)

result:
"3791785000.00000000000000000000,
 3791785000.00000000000000000000, 
       -512.00000000000000000000"
"3.791785E+09,
 3.791785E+09, 
-512"
```

How come they look the same but have a -512 difference ?
`res_ts` is `AppMgr.logon_info.res_ts` stored and reloaded from string.

Update: Some simple testing on .Net4 :

```
float a = 3791785472f;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F20}, {1}",a, a) );
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.#}, {1:00.#}",a, a) );
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.#}, {1:0,0.#}",a, a) );
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#.#}, {1:0,0.#}",a, a) );
```

results:

```
3791785000.00000000000000000000, 3.791785E+09
3791785000, 3791785000
3791785000, 3,791,785,000
3791785000, 3,791,785,000
```

link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hTEFGr

Everything is truncated to thousand in string representation. 
I wonder what should I do to save a big float as string without truncation to thousand?

Update:

```
double a = 3791785472f;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F20}, {1}",a, a) );
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.#}, {1:00.#}",a, a) );
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.#}, {1:0,0.#}",a, a) );
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#.#}, {1:0,0.#}",a, a) );

3791785472.00000000000000000000, 3791785472
3791785472, 3791785472
3791785472, 3,791,785,472
3791785472, 3,791,785,472
```

Oops. But why there is no overflow or any kind of error? Sounds like a risky business. Maybe I should simply avoid float wherever I can?

Comment: @Randall I checked that too, just add more trailing 0s. I'll update the post when am back.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem. However you should really be using `float.TryParse` rather than `float.Parse` within a *try/catch*. That's why it was created

Comment: @Flydog57  Thanks for the suggestion, it does looks neat. Though CF lacks this method, maybe I should extend it as suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that CF didn't have it. I wouldn't be surprised, however, if `double.TryParse` exists. In Framework V1.0, only the double version existed. It was soon implemented by all the other numeric types and by System.Enum

Comment: I tried it on dotnetfiddle.net with .net4, it still truncate to thousand. I wonder why there is no warning. The inexperenced .net user like me is trapped on this for hours in debuging a simple componet :-(.

Comment: When you need to store a floating point number as a string you should use the roundtrip format which does the conversion without loss of precision, i.e. use the "R" format specifier not "F20".